# Can't install missing features on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm working with cocos2d-x framework for c++ using Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 10.

When I try to open a solution for a created project, visual studio says some projects are unavailable. When I right click and go to "install missing feature(s)", visual studio says I have to install "Windows XP support for C++".

When I click to install I get a "Setup - Usage" window(that seems to be bigger than my screen). I don't see any button, so I hit enter, but nothing happens. Nothing downloads and nothing installs...

Does anyone have a solution to this?

The message is as follows:

> **Install Windows XP support for C++**
>
> Windows 7.1 SDK for targeting Windows XP
>
> The following projects will not be loaded unless you install the above
>   feature

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I re-installed visual studio with Universal Windows App Development Tools and some C++ options on the custom installation process. I also enabled Windows 10 developer mode. Doing those 2 things made it work.

Answer (score 1):

All that's needed is to add in Windows XP Support via the installation tool accessible from Control Panel. Steps:

- Close Visual Studio 2015
- Open Control Panel
- Select 'Programs and Options'
- Right click on 'Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2016'
- Select 'Change' from the menu (the only option)
- Once the installation tool has set up, select 'Modify'
- Expand Programming Languages --> Visual C++
- Select 'Windows XP Support for C++'.
- Proceed with the update.

Note that selecting 'Windows XP Support for C++' automatically selects its dependencies, 'Windows 8.1 SDK and Universal CRT SDK' and 'Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015'.

What I think might have happened for the OP was that in selecting Universal Windows App Development Tools and various C++ options, they hit upon 'Windows XP Support for C++' itself or something that had it as a dependency. So they may have various components installed unnecessarily now. :-(

Answer (score 0):

got your point.
Here are the steps to install it properly.
Go to the below site and try to install it. & select the option as per the snapshot attached here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

[image]

Also, if required, please refer to the below blog.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/